# teamviewerd not starting with lightdm on 13.10

Tags: lightdm, upstart, teamviewer

I've installed the upstart-job for Teamviewer 9. According to the config it should start when dbus and lightdm is running, see:

```
start on (
              (started dbus         or
               started init-system-dbus)
              and
             (
              starting-dm           or
              started gdm           or
              started kdm           or
              started lightdm       or
              started lxdm          or
              started prefdm        or
              started xdm)
            )
```

As you can see, both are started here on my Ubuntu 13.10 but teamviewerd does not start automatically:

```
root@surf:~# initctl list |grep dbus
dbus start/running, process 807
root@surf:~# initctl list |grep lightdm
lightdm start/running, process 2336
root@surf:~# initctl list |grep teamviewerd
teamviewerd stop/waiting
```

In the log I get (after a reboot):

```
root@surf:~# cat /var/log/upstart/teamviewerd.log
method return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> dest=:1.6 reply_serial=2
   uint32 1
```

If I start it manually it works as expected:

```
root@surf:~# initctl start teamviewerd 
teamviewerd start/running, process 13796
```

What is wrong with this job?

Answer (score 0):

There are some integrated deamon commands in teamviewer. At least on 8th version.

```
teamviewer --daemon status           show current status of the TeamViewer daemon
teamviewer --daemon start            start                      TeamViewer daemon
teamviewer --daemon stop             stop                       TeamViewer daemon
teamviewer --daemon restart          stop/start                 TeamViewer daemon
teamviewer --daemon disable          disable                    TeamViewer daemon - don't start daemon on system startup
teamviewer --daemon enable           enable                     TeamViewer daemon - start daemon on system startup (default)
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2092298)

Comment: Correct, i used 'enable' to create this upstart-job. But it doesn't start automatically anyhow.

Comment: Did you used with root privileges, correct ? Maybe you have to communicate with the teamviewer team and inform them.

Comment: I know, this answer is late :)
I decided to start teamviewer in a start script as I couldn't solve it otherwise. Only disadvantage is: the teamviewer window is open after the user logged in. I found no other solution and havn't touched that station since then (except for updates).